# Dynamically increase Google Map v3 search area when no results returned to include at least 1?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I followed this example and successfully built a store locator:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/localsearch/places.html

My problem is that some searches do not return any results when the search location is not near a well populated area.  To see what I mean you can load the example URL above and try either search below which combines the "T-Mobile" Keyword with the zip for either Death Valley, CA or Yosemite Valley, CA:

T-Mobile 92328
T-Mobile 95389

The Google API is not sending any results for either of these ZIP codes. (Makes sense since there are probably no T-Mobile stores within a great distance)

I need to find a way to handle this and did extensive research but found nothing.  Is there a way to either:

1. Widen the search area if the Google API does not return a result to include at least 1 result.
2. Start with a wider search area to minimize the occurrences of no T-Mobile stores being found within a given area?

Thanks for your time!